# Como poner autoplay a videos que no sean de Youtube?

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo una duda, se podrá poner `autoplay` a vídeos que no sean de youtube?, como por ejemplo a otros enlaces o vídeos insertados en paginas web de terceros.

He visto que en youtube ponen `?autoplay=1` al final del link y funciona pero no  funciona en este link.

```
 <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pdvh_mEnkXPKA3jivYIpYKTaoukxH5p3Yg/preview"></iframe>
```

Comment: Usando HTML5, al usar la etiqueta [video](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) puedes usar el atributo `Autoplay`.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave Lo intente pero no obtuve resultados. tendrás un ejemplo por si acaso?.

Answer (score 1):

puedes probar con la etiqueta `<video>` de html5 la cual tiene un atributo para reproducción automática:

```html
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
       <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
       <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
     </video>
```

Comment: He probado con la etiqueta <video> pero el detalle es que el video lo tengo subido en google drive, al poner el link no me muestra nada.
 <source src="Aqui debería ir el link?" type="video/mp4">

Comment: un problema ese detalle, no vi forma de obtener el link directo del video.

Comment: Probé con esa etiqueta '<video>' pero no me muestra el vídeo.

'<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
 <source src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pdvh_mEnkXPKA3jivYIpYKTaoukxH5p3Yg/preview" type="video/mp4">
 <source src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pdvh_mEnkXPKA3jivYIpYKTaoukxH5p3Yg/preview" type="video/ogg">
 </video> '

Comment: me temo que no funciona a menos que tengas es enlace directo al video. En este caso google drive te da un enlace a un reproductor.

Comment: Gracias @engel por tu apoyo. :)

Answer (score 1):

Para tu caso específico, tuve que ver el HTML de ese video. Allí hallé la URL que puedes usar para ver el video:

Esta es la [URL](https://r6---sn-cvb7ln7l.c.drive.google.com/videoplayback?id=f4ad6234cb575705&itag=18&source=picasa&requiressl=yes&ttl=transient&mm=30&mn=sn-cvb7ln7l&ms=nxu&mv=u&pl=23&ei=oO9KWZf6DsvYqQW53oP4Cw&driveid=1pdvh_mEnkXPKA3jivYIpYKTaoukxH5p3Yg&mime=video/mp4&lmt=1449416645575513&mt=1498082978&ip=181.59.58.201&ipbits=0&expire=1498097632&cp=QVJOWkFfVlZRQ1hNOlFsSUdaRFdwSURN&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,id,itag,source,requiressl,ttl,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,ei,driveid,mime,lmt,cp&signature=22BE366BA5501E7E24ABEB13C56D1E8B95DD5D54.97B82E8E1241C0031A02F0D92F5EA5E66AB502E2&key=ck2&app=explorer&cpn=giKSs-BY1XsfKv9z&c=WEB&cver=1.20170620):

Y este es el resultado:

```html
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay src="https://r6---sn-cvb7ln7l.c.drive.google.com/videoplayback?id=f4ad6234cb575705&itag=18&source=picasa&requiressl=yes&ttl=transient&mm=30&mn=sn-cvb7ln7l&ms=nxu&mv=u&pl=23&ei=oO9KWZf6DsvYqQW53oP4Cw&driveid=1pdvh_mEnkXPKA3jivYIpYKTaoukxH5p3Yg&mime=video/mp4&lmt=1449416645575513&mt=1498082978&ip=181.59.58.201&ipbits=0&expire=1498097632&cp=QVJOWkFfVlZRQ1hNOlFsSUdaRFdwSURN&sparams=ip,ipbits,expire,id,itag,source,requiressl,ttl,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,ei,driveid,mime,lmt,cp&signature=22BE366BA5501E7E24ABEB13C56D1E8B95DD5D54.97B82E8E1241C0031A02F0D92F5EA5E66AB502E2&key=ck2&app=explorer&cpn=giKSs-BY1XsfKv9z&c=WEB&cver=1.20170620">
Su navegador no soporta la etiqueta VIDEO.
 </video>
```

Si por algún motivo no puedes obtener esta URL, me temo que debes investigar mas cómo puedes obtener la URL de un video en Google Drive.

Comment: Gracias @MauricioAriasOlave. al parecer la etiqueta <video> no soporta los links. no me muestra el vídeo cuando los inserto.

Answer (score 1):

algunos dispositivos como los de apple bloquean la opcion de autoplay asi que hazlo via javascript:

```
<body onload='playfunc()'>

// el id es importante para reproducirlo al cargar la pagina

<video id='video' width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
   <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
 </video> 

</body>

<script>

// con esta funcion reproduciras el video al cargar la pagina en dispositivos que no soporten autoplay

function playfunc(){
document.getElementById('video').play();

}

</script>
```